# How to make a path disappear after some arbitrary time using MapPolyline in QML?

Tags: qt, timer, qml

This is the code that I have in QML. I want to know how I can add timer so each coordinate disappears after some arbitrary time.

```
        MapPolyline {
            id:         mapPolyLine
            line.width: 8
            line.color: "blue"
            path: [
                { latitude: -34, longitude: 129.0 },
                { latitude: -35, longitude: 133.0 },
                { latitude: -34, longitude: 135.0 },
                { latitude: -33, longitude: 134.0 }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is to associate each coordinate with an identifier, so when any timer is triggered then obtain the index using the identifier and then remove it from the model. And every time the number of items in the model is changed then recalculate the path.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtLocation 5.15
import QtPositioning 5.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListModel{
        id: polylineModel
        dynamicRoles: true
        onCountChanged: ()=> _internals.updatePolyline()
    }
    QtObject{
        id: _internals
        property int identifier_counter: 0
        function updatePolyline(){
            var path = []
            for(var i =0; i < polylineModel.count; ++i){
                var obj = polylineModel.get(i);
                path.push({"latitude": obj.latitude, "longitude": obj.longitude});
            }
            mapPolyLine.path = path
        }

        function deletePoint(identifier){
            for(var i =0; i < polylineModel.count; ++i){
                var obj = polylineModel.get(i);
                if(obj.identifier === identifier){
                    polylineModel.remove(i);
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        property Component timerComponent: Timer{
            id: timer
            repeat: false
            required property int identifier
            onTriggered: ()=> {
                             destroy();
                             _internals.deletePoint(identifier)
                         }
        }

        function appendPoint(latitude, longitude,  interval){
            var timer = timerComponent.createObject(polylineModel,
                                                    {"identifier": identifier_counter,
                                                        "interval": interval
                                                    })
            timer.start();
            polylineModel.append({"longitude": longitude, "latitude": latitude, "identifier": identifier_counter})
            identifier_counter++;
        }
        function init(){
            appendPoint(-34, 129, 1000);
            appendPoint(-35, 133, 5000);
            appendPoint(-34, 135, 3000);
            appendPoint(-33, 134, 2000);
        }
    }
    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: Plugin{
            name: "osm"
        }
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(-34, 135)
        zoomLevel: 8
        MapPolyline {
            id: mapPolyLine
            line.width: 8
            line.color: "blue"
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: _internals.init()
}
```